# How to reduce an array of objects with same dates (property)?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Example:

`Array A`

```
[0] { date="01-03-2016",  foo=30}
[1] { date="02-03-2016",  foo=17}
[2] { date="03-03-2016",  foo=15}
[3] { date="04-03-2016",  foo=28}
[4] { date="01-03-2016",  bar=33}
[5] { date="04-03-2016",  bar=34}
```

`Array B (Wanted array)`

```
[0] { date="01-03-2016",  foo=30 ,bar=33}
[1] { date="02-03-2016",  foo=17}
[2] { date="03-03-2016",  foo=15}
[3] { date="04-03-2016",  foo=28, bar=34}
```

I tried with `array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);` but I guess the arrays need have the same properties name to work.

Comment: Are there other keys that could intersect for the same date? E.g. the `foo` or `bar` keys?

Comment: No, the objects  will have just 2 properties the date and one more

Comment: What I mean to ask is can a situation like this occur?
`{date='01-01-2000', foo=25}, {date='01-01-2000', foo=16}`. As you can see, these entries have equal dates, the same secondary key, but different values for the secondary key. Should your algorithm accommodate this case?

Comment: @wilkesybear no that can't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by temporarily using the `date` property as an array key. Here's the simplest example I could think of:

```
$tmp = [];

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $tmp[$val['date']] = array_merge(
        isset($tmp[$val['date']]) ? $tmp[$val['date']] : [],
        $val
    );
}

$result = array_values($tmp);
```

You use `$val['date']` as a key in the `$tmp` array. Now, as the `foreach` iterates over you array, it will merge whatever is in the `$tmp` array under the same date with the current value.

Then, if you wish, you can strip the keys from `$tmp` using `array_values`.